# Configuring the model hook and setupController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm having trouble getting my Route's model and setupController hooks to work correctly. I'm still relatively new to ember. Here's my code

```
IS.AlbumsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (params) {
        return IS.Album.find(params.album_id);
    },
    setupController: function(controller, user) {
        var controller = this.controllerFor("application");
        var data = controller.get("currentUser").get('albums');
        controller.set('content', data);
    }
}
```

And my models look like this

```
IS.User = DS.Model.extend({
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    password: DS.attr('string'),
    albums: DS.hasMany('IS.Album'),
});

IS.Album = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    user: DS.belongsTo('IS.User')
});
```

While this works, an extra query to my api is sent to "api/albums" preceding the query that actually gets the correct data (at url "api/albums/ids[]=0&ids[]=1"). Is there anyway to stop this extra query form happening?

Comment: Tried returning `null` in the `model` hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
IS.AlbumsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        var controller = this.controllerFor("application");
        return controller.get('currentUser.albums');
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it! It seems so simple now. Thanks for your help!